# Default material importing images as planes

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

When importing images as planes the default material has specularity of 50%.

I want to import a lot of images, but with specularity of 0%. Or in some other projects I need all the images to be emission maps.

Is there a way to prepare a Principled node, (or even shader nodes) to be used by default when importing Images as Planes?

Comment: can be done using blenders python API

Answer (score 1):

Making them use an emission shader can be set under the import settings:
[image]

To edit principled bsdf for all images, here is what you need to do:

1. Import images with `Principled` option set
2. Select all images you want to edit with `Principled` material
3. Go to `Scripting` tab
   [image]
4. Set the text file name to be (`.py`):
   [image]
5. paste the following code:

```
    import bpy
    
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        mat = obj.data.materials[0]
        nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
        nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[5].default_value = 0.0 #specify your specular value here
```

6. Run the code (make sure all images are selected):
   [image]
7. Check out your image planes materials, specular should be the one you specified

Comment: Nice. I will take a look and make some tests later.

Answer (score 1):

**Specularity** - You can edit add-on for you ... navigate to addons folder inside Blender (according to your OS)

- open *io_import_images_as_planes.py* file in some Text Editor
- copy line **1005** `core_shader.inputs['Specular'].default_value = 0.0`
- and paste after line **998** ... save and reopen Blender.

... if you need more default adjustments of shader you can easily replicate similar to other values of BSDF, seems to me self-descriptive even without scripting knowledge ... like me :)

**Emission** - already pointed by @kemplerart :)